# google font cdn to serve eof, svg, ttf

Tags: html, asp.net, css, fonts, font-face

Does Google also host those font formats ? In web site I see it refers to woff. Does this mean that all other formats must be served from local machine ?

I want to have something like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('Google cdn path to GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
       url('Google cdn path to  GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), url('Google cdn path to  GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

But google provides link only to woff.

Answer (score 0):

Google will only serve the font type that will work with the browser that requests the CSS file/font. Reason is that it reduces bandwidth and the number of requests for Google, and the client requesting the font.

Comment: So how I can provide the link to lets say eot file inside font-face ?

Comment: @Tamerlane You could switch your user agent to one that requires the eot file so it. But, instead of trying to guess where the Google CDN places things, I would recommend using the Google provided CSS file that they give you when you pick the fonts.

Comment: @Tamerlane Yep! Or the `<link />` on the web page would work as well.